# How can I tell magit to ignore specific modified files?

Tags: magit, git

I am working on a project where `webpack`'s `bundle.js` is part of the repository. This file is gigantic and has many diffs and slows magit down. Is there a way I can tell magit to ignore this file when computing unstaged changes? To reiterate, I don't want to untrack the file or add it to my .gitignore, I just want magit to ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell `git` to temporarily ignore changes to a certain file using:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

and later you can undo that using:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Magit will respect that setting too.

Comment: Can I tell magit to ignore a "noisy" auto-generated file like readme.md which is an org-mode report? I want it in git so it's pushed to GitHub but unfortunately, org regenerates all its internal IDs when exporting to markdown and that makes a lot of noise in git status ;)